# Android Library to get count of lines in an image

Tags: android, image-processing, image-recognition

Is there any android image recognition / manipulation library that can help me count number of lines in an image, like this one?

[image]

I think it would be possible with OpenCV + Java but I am trying to avoid learning OpenCV if this task can be done with some readily available library or even service for that matter.
Thanks

Comment: Asking for external resources is off-topic. Please see [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you know to access the individual pixels, this is a trivial task. Sampling a single column in the middle, just count the number of transitions from black to white.

Comment: therefor you could convolute the column with [1 -1]. The number of lines is equal to the number of non zero values in the filtered column divided by two. Or you just count the positiv or negativ values. Maybe you need to apply a padding to the column to detect lines at the top and at the bottom of the image

Answer (score -2):

You can use [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html). It is pretty good at this. And you can find tutorials [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/tutorials.html).

I got some experience with it so I suggest you to do this:

Pseudocode:

1. Load the image to OpenCv.
2. Transform the image to grey scale.
3. Apply Canny effect.
4. Apply Hough transform.
5. You will get a vector with your main lines.

Comment: Besides that the question is off-topic, and that op wants to avoid opencv, why not simply invert the image and get the number of connected components?

Comment: Tesseract is another library for doing this. http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/

Comment: No, it isn't. Tesseract is for ocr.